# Saldo acumulado com múltiplas contas - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, query

Estou tendo problemas ao criar um extrato de conta que tenha a opção de filtrar todas as conta e/ou só algumas contas.

Estou usando esse SQL para aparecer esses registro dessa forma

```
select
  bancos.id,
  bancos.date,
  bancos.type,
  bancos.description,
  bancos.account_plan_id,
  bancos.money * case
    when bancos.type = 2 then -1
    else 1
  end valor,
  (
    select
      sum(
        s.money * case
          when s.type = 2 then -1
          else 1
        end
      )
    from
      bancos as s
    where
      s.date < bancos.date
      or s.date = bancos.date
      and s.id <= bancos.id
  ) as saldo
from
  `bancos`
where
  `date` between '2020-01-01'
  and '2020-02-29'
  and `banco_id` in ('1', '6', '7')
  and `company_id` = 1
order by
  `bancos`.`date` asc
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered table-reponsive" >
            <thead>
                    <tr>
                            
                            <th>Data</th>
                            <th>Conta</th>
                            <th>Plano de Contas</th>
                            <th>Descrição</th>                            
                            <th>Valor</th>
                            <th>Saldo</th>
                            
                        </tr>
                
                </thead>
    
                <tbody>
                                                <tr id="lists">                           
                        
                            <td>01/01/2020</td>
                            <td>Banco 1</td>
                            <td>Recebimento em Dinheiro</td>
                            <td>Teste</td>                            
                            <td class="text-green"> 500,00  </td>
                            <td> 1.150,00</td>
                           
                           
                        </tr>   
                                            <tr id="lists">                           
                        
                            <td>10/01/2020</td>
                            <td>Banco 2</td>
                            <td>OBRAS</td>
                            <td>sd</td>                            
                            <td class="text-danger"> -150,00 </td>
                            <td> 1.000,00</td>
                           
                           
                        </tr>   
                                            <tr id="lists">                           
                          
                            <td>28/01/2020</td>
                            <td>Banco 1</td>
                            <td>Internet</td>
                            <td>sdfg</td>                            
                            <td class="text-danger"> -100,00</td>
                            <td> 900,00</td>
                           
                           
                        </tr>   
                                            <tr id="lists">                           
                        
                            <td>28/01/2020</td>
                            <td>Banco 1</td>
                            <td>Recebimento em Dinheiro</td>
                            <td>sd</td>                            
                            <td class="text-green"> 500,00 </td>
                            <td> 1.400,00</td>
                           
                           
                        </tr>   
                                            <tr id="lists">                           
                         
                            <td>29/01/2020</td>
                            <td>Banco 1</td>
                            <td>Recebimento em Dinheiro</td>
                            <td>sd</td>                            
                            <td class="text-green"> 520,00  </td>
                            <td> 1.920,00</td>
                           
                           
                        </tr>   
                                            <tr id="lists">                           
                         
                            <td>30/01/2020</td>
                            <td>Banco 1</td>
                            <td>Recebimento em Dinheiro</td>
                            <td>df</td>                            
                            <td class="text-green"> 500,00  </td>
                            <td> 2.420,00</td>
                           
                           
                        </tr>   
                                            <tr id="lists">                           
                         
                            <td>30/01/2020</td>
                            <td>Banco 1</td>
                            <td>Recebimento em Dinheiro</td>
                            <td>sd</td>                            
                            <td class="text-green"> 500,00  </td>
                            <td> 2.920,00</td>
                           
                           
                        </tr>   
                         <tr id="lists">                          
                          
                            <td>30/01/2020</td>
                            <td>Banco 2</td>
                            <td>Internet</td>
                            <td>df</td>                            
                            <td class="text-danger"> -150,00  <small title="Pago" class="label pull-right bg-green"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></small></td>
                            <td> 2.770,00</td>
                           
                           
                        </tr>   
                        <tr >  
                           
                            <td>31/01/2020</td>
                            <td>Banco 3</td>
                            <td>Recebimento em Dinheiro</td>
                            <td>df</td>                            
                            <td class="text-green"> 150,00 </td>
                            <td> 2.920,00</td>
                           
                           
                        </tr>   
                                   
                </tbody>
          </table>
```

Ai aí tudo bem, mas quando eu coloco para filtrar somente 1 conta, a soma do saldo acumulado, não fica unicamente daquela conta. não estou conseguindo construir a query de forma correta para atender as duas situações todas as notas e somente um ou 2 contas, mas somar o saldo de forma dinâmica.

Comment: Provavelmente você não irá conseguir fazer isso no banco, o correto é você somar no front, ou então você vai ter que calcular no banco cada tipo de filtro que terá que ser realizado e criar uma nova coluna que com o tipo de filtro e unificar essa base com union all.

Comment: Depois de varias tentativas consegui resolver o problemas, coloquei os ids do banco_id no subselect

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi resolvido da seguinte forma, informei os ids do banco_id dentro do subselect

```
select
  bancos.id,
  bancos.date,
  bancos.type,
  bancos.description,
  bancos.account_plan_id,
  bancos.money * case
    when bancos.type = 2 then -1
    else 1
  end valor,
  (
    select
      sum(
        s.money * case
          when s.type = 2 then -1
          else 1
        end
      )
    from
      bancos as s
    where
      s.banco_id in ('1','6','7') <<< Linha adicionada
      and s.date < bancos.date
      or s.date = bancos.date
      and s.id <= bancos.id
  ) as saldo
from
  `bancos`
where
  `date` between '2020-01-01'
  and '2020-02-29'
  and `banco_id` in ('1', '6', '7')
  and `company_id` = 1
order by
  `bancos`.`date` asc
```

Com isso o problema foi resolvido.